# While Loop and Cursor in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am working on my first Android project and i have some difficulties with the SQLite database. I need to accumulate for example the `sum(amount) for which name= cash and debit_credit= dr`. There is no for loop in sql so how can I do that with the while loop and the cursor? Below is my table:

```
ID NAME Debit_Credit AMOUNT
1  cash    dr         100
2  equip   cr         100
3  cash    dr         500
4  A/R     cr         500
```

Comment: you can check my edited answer and see if this way will work for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT Sum(amount) FROM table WHERE name=? AND debit_credit=?` (this really is an SQL question)

**UPDATE:** For this simple query that only returns a number, you can use `.simpleQueryForLong()`:

```
SQLiteStatement st = db.compileStatement("SELECT Sum(amount) ...", ...);
long sum = st.simpleQueryForLong();
```

Comment: Yes but my real question is how to attached it to the cursor and display as an int. THis is my code but the c.getString(1) causes error.                                                            Cursor c=datasource.database.rawQuery("SELECT sum(amount)as Total FROM entries WHERE name= 'cash' AND debit_credit='dr'", null);
   c.moveToFirst();
   Log.i(LOGTAG, c.getString(1));

Comment: The value in the first returned column would be `c.getString(0)`.

Comment: well, it would ideally be a number, answer updated with Java code.

Comment: That was it. it was located at c.getString(0) and not c.getString(1). Thank you a lot :)